# Is the Instagram ClientID specific to each person using it?

Tags: javascript, instagram-api

I'm sure this is a 101 question but I haven't found a definitive answer yet.

I'm working on an Instagram widget for Adobe Muse based on an open source Javascript client. This requires an Instagram clientID for accessing the API. I've registered one for myself and all works fine. Is the ClientID unique for each person using an instance of the widget on their own site or does it just require it to reference mine?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need only one Instagram client for your widget. It seems that you've registered one already.

Your widget should be able to authenticate each user using your client ID.

Since your widget is using Javascript, you'll have to use implicit authentication.

https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token

If a user grants access to your client, a unique access token for that user will be returned.

http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Your widget should use the access token for accessing Instagram API.

You'll find more information on [Instagram Developer Portal - Authentication](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)